# Can an authorized user of a credit card build their credits from using the card

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit, credit-history

I have a few years' credit history, and most of the time a FICO score of 780 to 820. I believe my spouse never had any credit accounts. If I add her as an authorized user of one of my credit cards, can she establish her credit from using the card??

Comment: There are a bunch of other questions in the Related list in the sidebar to the right, as well.

Comment: @Joe I saw that question but it is about **improving** each other's credit score between 2 people. I am asking if doing so can **establish** someone's credit score, as the person has no credit history.

Comment: The answer in that question is the answer to your question: yes, it may help a bit.

Comment: I added a slightly more generic answer on that question that should apply to your case as well.